# How do I get an alert box in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, wordpress, radio-button

Sorry for the noob question, but I'm starting to learn Jquery, and I have followed what seems to be a very straightforward tiny code that displays an alert box. However, when I try it on codepen or my wordpress site, it doesn't work.
Here is HTML

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#my_radio_box').change(function(){
    alert('Radio Box has been changed!');
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="my_radio_box">
  <input type="radio" name="my_options" value="option 1"> Option 1
  <input type="radio" name="my_options" value="option 2"> Option 2
  <input type="radio" name="my_options" value="option 3"> Option 3
</form>
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: Yes the reference was missing, and that's what made it work on codepen. However, my wordpress site displays the jquery as text. What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `name` attribute in the selector like:

```
$(':radio[name=my_options]').change(function(){
```

**Working Code Example:**

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(':radio[name=my_options]').change(function(){
    alert('Radio Box has been changed to '+ this.value);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="my_radio_box">
  <input type="radio" name="my_options" value="option 1"> Option 1
  <input type="radio" name="my_options" value="option 2"> Option 2
  <input type="radio" name="my_options" value="option 3"> Option 3
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function(){
  $('input[type="radio"]').click(function(){
    if ($(this).is(':checked'))
    {
      alert($(this).val());
    }
  });
});
```

If you give your radio buttons a class then you can replace the code `$('input[type="radio"]')` with `$('.someclass')`